# Getting USB port name and details

Tags: powershell, usb

How can I get all USB ports and related details like port name, using Power Shell Script?

I tried [`Win32_USBControllerDevice class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-usbcontrollerdevice). But did not get a port name.

Answer (score 3):

```
gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} |select name,description,  deviceID, manufacturer | format-table -group by manufacturer
```

### Some explanation

The WMI class `WIN32_USBControllerDevice` describes the connection between USB controllers (The `Antecedent`) and their logical devices `[CIM_LOGICALDEVICE]` (the `Dependent`)

```
PS>gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |fl Antecedent,Dependent Antecedent : \\.\root\cimv2:Win32_USBController.DeviceID="PCI\\VEN_8086 &DEV_3A35&SUBSYS_02931028&REV_00\\3&172E68DD&0&E9" Dependent : \\.\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\\ROOT_HUB\\4& 10B856B0&0"
```

now you can check `win32_PnPEntity` to get more info about the device ex:

```
gwmi Win32_PnPEntity -Filter "DeviceID='USBSTOR\\DISK&..'"
```

Comment: the WMI class WIN32_USBControllerDevice describes the connection between USB controllers (The Antecedent) and their logical devices [CIM_LOGICALDEVICE] (the Dependent)  
`PS>gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |fl Antecedent,Dependent


Antecedent : \\.\root\cimv2:Win32_USBController.DeviceID="PCI\\VEN_8086
             &DEV_3A35&SUBSYS_02931028&REV_00\\3&172E68DD&0&E9"
Dependent  : \\.\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="USB\\ROOT_HUB\\4&
             10B856B0&0"
`
now you can check win32_PnPEntity to get more info about the device  ex:
`gwmi Win32_PnPEntity -Filter "DeviceID='USBSTOR\\DISK&..'"`

Comment: @MattLin USB ports don't have names. It is a bus, it doesn't matter what connector you use. 
If you are actually talking about a USB device whose driver emulates a serial port (like "COM5"),you've got toh check the Win32_SerialPort class